# file location different on computers and space issues

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have the below code and currently checks computer for version info and service status.

The problem I have is that servers have the located .exe in different places:

1. C:\program files\snare\snarecore.exe
2. C:\program files (x86)\snare\snarecore.exe
3. D:\apps\snare\snarecore.exe

How do I get the script below to run the right version? I think I can use the path that the service is checking? I am doing this all remotly and have rights to the server and works fine - but I am having to possiblt make three (or more!) scripts just based on all three locations of where the executable is!

Also, for the ones that have a space in the name (../program file..) where do I put the quotes so that powershell can read the whole line and not error out due to the space in the name?

CODE:

```
clear
$ErrorActionPreference = "silentlycontinue"

$Logfile = "C:\temp\output_cdrive.log"

Function LogWrite
{
    param([string]$logstring)

    Add-Content $Logfile -Value $logstring
}

$computer = Get-Content -Path c:\temp\servers2.txt

foreach ($computer1 in $computer){

$Service = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "Name = 'Snare'" -ComputerName $computer1

    if (test-connection $computer1 -quiet) 
    {
        $version = (Get-Command ""\\$computer1\c$\Program Files (x86)\Snare\SnareCore.exe"").FileVersionInfo.FileVersion

            if($Service.state -eq 'Running')
            {
                LogWrite "$computer1 STARTED $version"
            }
            else
            {
                LogWrite "$computer1 STOPPED $version"
            }
    }
    else 
    {
        LogWrite "$computer1 is down" -foregroundcolor RED
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check the pathname property of you service to get the exe location :

```
PS>(Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "name='spooler'").pathname
C:\Windows\System32\spoolsv.exe
```

Comment: this seems to work fine - but it does not do the ones that have a space in the path name....any idea how I can get the code to execute with the ones with a name in the pathname?

Comment: what is the problem exactly? just use quotes (") between your path and this should work

Comment: James answered it - I was using quotes but it was not working - the problem was I needed three different quotes!

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution is to use a path variable, assign that variable each of the three different paths in turn, and write your actual checks as a function using that variable.

Comment: sounds like a good idea...but I have no idea where to start with that...I will try and implement it anyway..

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the double quotes using the backtick:

```
 "`"\\$computer1\c$\Program Files (x86)\Snare\SnareCore.exe`""
```